# Texto dentro de una imagen con Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Me gustaría saber como hacer el siguiente diseño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que cuando pase el mouse, salga ese efecto con el sombreado y texto blanco, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

Lo que he podido probar:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <img src="imagen1" class="img-fluid"><br>
    <p style="margin-top:-10px;">Habilidad Sociales</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <img src="imagen1" class="img-fluid"><br>
    <p style="margin-top:-10px;">Compensación lectora</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <img src="imagen1" class="img-fluid"><br>
    <p style="margin-top:-10px;">Estimulación</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pero non tengo el resultado que quiero :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```css
.imagebox {
  background: black;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.imagebox img {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s opacity;
}

.imagebox .imagebox-desc {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s padding;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.imagebox:hover img {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.imagebox:hover .imagebox-desc {
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="imagebox">
        <a href="#hola">
          <img src="//placeimg.com/400/400/animals"  class="category-banner img-responsive">
          <span class="imagebox-desc">Habilidad Sociales</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="imagebox">
        <a href="#hola">
          <img src="//placeimg.com/400/400/animals"  class="category-banner img-responsive">
          <span class="imagebox-desc">Compensación lectora</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="imagebox">
        <a href="#hola">
          <img src="//placeimg.com/400/400/animals"  class="category-banner img-responsive">
          <span class="imagebox-desc">Estimulación</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Checate la referencia en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/luisintosh/pen/gPGXOp?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=0f3c84cccbae6ed4047e0ab2b127ba60488d6f62-1603730750-0-AR7uuesnJwdVe-ceJa6TpDAChOXygwtDt8H8PGW2UkkRsQsoa4cWxd3qc8jwWNanoHzUwotVMwj1cGwtPU2WSc1Eb9AZ5t6FDo2aD3PD6zPIq3cDQRD6uJQvAZ3ELQA5dXAVSGx8ZGkSJKcSLhpoxSebdnuNwtkH0dZf_tBLCfERvIVJcO6aNUvKZFQLaDtdgPNlpR6UiWacu1NIKQxbQijym8lkjKRGTMEdaNsYKMaweBuNkvfPqeXswdaU07i2cObNIE7vL-Tk9R1wZdpFj2ZEMo1Todls6LfWzzlWMfVzK0M0bYt1XBAnxWMIVZK0VH5c2qBJGFWaq-iHysFzKG7-yPcs-j9k9rCcX8G1xpB6) :)

Comment: Gracias crack, me ah funcionado genial